# Solving for the constant, integrals

Tags: integration, functions

I'm just learning the basics of integral calculus - if someone could check my work, that'd be awesome.

if 
$$
  f(x) =
   \begin{cases}
    ce^{-2x}    & \text{if } x > 0 \\
    0       & \text{otherwise} 
   \end{cases}
$$

and I'm asked to find the value of the constant $c$ and sketch the PDF of $X$, does this make sense?

Can I say $f(x) = f(1)$,
take the derivative of $$ce^{-2x} = \frac{-1}{2}ce^{-2x}$$
\begin{align*}
&1 = (-1/2)ce^{-2}\\
\implies& -2 = ce^{-2}\\
\implies& -2/e^{-2} = c\\
\implies& c = -14.778
\end{align*}

Comment: I'm pretty sure my answer is wrong, because the constant is a negative, and x has to be x > 0....or does that not matter?

Answer (score 1):

As it is a PDF then $\int_0^{\inf} f(x)dx =1$. Use this to fix c.

Comment: that asks for the antiderivative of f(x), right? isn't that the same thing as what I did above?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. By dividing c*EXP(-2x)/cEXP(-2x) gives you one, and it gives 1 = -1/2, which is false. Remember that x is a variable and can take many values, so c is an arbitrary constant found by using a range value. In differential equations they use that principle all the time for find exponential decay and half-life... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay gives a strong picture. 
Great question out of curiosity though! When I first learned about that I wondered the same thing, but it didn't help with the test.

And that discontinuous function is used in statistics all the time, so yes that part makes sense. For example: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polya+aeppli+distribution.